# Artifact present in 2 maven repositories - repositories conflict

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, nexus

This is likely to be solved with Nexus configuration.

We use maven for hadoop development. Nexus is configured as mirror for all repository, and repositories are added in nexus public group. (see [Is there better way of configuring repositories in Nexus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14576124/is-there-better-way-of-configuring-repositories-in-nexus))

I discovered that hadoop-core artifact version 1.0.4 is shown to come from spring-roo-repository http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release/
Nexus shows only pom avaiable, althow  I see jar via browser path /nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-core/1.0.4/

How to make hadoop-core to come from Maven Central?

[image: Nexus screnshot]

Comment: Did you run a build requesting the hadoop artifact already? The search results are not necessarily everything that is availabe, it's only what is in the index. If your central proxy is not set to download the index, you won't find the artifact with a search until you actually triggered Nexus to download it.

Comment: When I did the set up of our Nexus server, I found a lot of people that experienced troubles when the remote indexing was enabled. I don't know if this has been fixed since, but it might be safer to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, one solution would be to configure 2 different proxies, and have references to these 2 proxies in your settings.xml (and/or) pom.

You could then have control at least on the **order** used for the search of a dependency.

This might be useful to separate spring repo this way, as Spring has a nasty(IMO) habit of duplicating dependencies (sometimes with a different groupId or artefactId, but not always at it seems).

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the Maven Central Proxy repository is ordered before the Spring-Roo-Repository in your public group.

This is from Nexus documentation [Managing Groups](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/confignx-sect-managing-groups.html)

> Note that the order of the repositories listed in Order Group
>   Repositories is important. When Nexus searches for an artifact in a
>   group it will return the first match. To reorder a repository in this
>   list, click and the drag the repositories and groups in the Ordered
>   Group Repositories selection list.